# Switch multiple classes and vars with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my first attempt doing pagination links with angular.

```
<div ng-init="page1 = true" ng-show="page1"></div>
<div ng-show="page2"></div>
<div ng-show="page3"></div>

<div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button ng-click="page1 = true; page2 = false; page3 = false" ng-class="page1 ? 'btn btn-info' : 'btn btn-default'">1</button>
        <button ng-click="page2 = true; page1 = false; page3 = false" ng-class="page2 ? 'btn btn-info' : 'btn btn-default'">2</button>
        <button ng-click="page3 = true; page1 = false; page2 = false" ng-class="page3 ? 'btn btn-info' : 'btn btn-default'">3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the moment when I click button for page2, I'm manually making buttons for page1 and page3 to switch classes through setting page1 and page3 vars to false.

Is there a way, when clicking page2 button, to make other similar buttons dynamically switch classes and set vars to false out of the scope of the element being clicked?

Comment: ng-repeat and store the pages list in the scope.

Comment: Yeah, ng-repeat is your solution here. Just google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining multiple vars such as page1, page2, page3 you could also create two methods on your $scope:

```
var active = 1; // Default active page
$scope.activate = function(page) {
    active = page;
}

$scope.isActive = function(page) {
    return page === active;
};
```

Then from your template you could do something like:

```
<div ng-show="isActive(1)"></div>
<div ng-show="isActive(2)"></div>
<div ng-show="isActive(3)"></div>

<div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button ng-click="activate(1)" ng-class="isActive(1) ? 'btn btn-info' : 'btn btn-default'">1</button>
        <button ng-click="activate(2)" ng-class="isActive(2) ? 'btn btn-info' : 'btn btn-default'">2</button>
        <button ng-click="activate(3)" ng-class="isActive(3) ? 'btn btn-info' : 'btn btn-default'">3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Later on you might do something like this in your template to make it more dynamic:

```
<div ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-show="isActive(page.index)"></div>

<div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button ng-repeat ng-click="activate(page.index)" ng-class="isActive(page.index) ? 'btn btn-info' : 'btn btn-default'">{{page.index}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note:
The dynamic example is assuming a property on your $scope which looks similar to this:

```
$scope.pages = [
    {index: 1},
    {index: 2},
    {index: 3}
];
```

You'll find more info on ngRepeat on this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Should the first portion of your code be in a controller?

Comment: Yes, this is where you should have access to the $scope. You get get more info on controllers here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller